# Select WebElement by text within HTML

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I've been trying to select this WebElement for a while. It's a sign up button on the front page of the web application I test. I was wondering, is there a method I could use to grab text within the HTML to define a WebElement?

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div style="">
      <div style="transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(0.5, 0.5) rotate(0deg);">
        <div role="img">
          <img src="images/lsloginform/newskin/try_it_normal.png?1444658058414">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="transform: translate(0px, 75px) scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);">
        <canvas height="7" width="75" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 75px; height: 7px;"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div style="transform: translate(0px, 82px) scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);">
        <div style="font-family: franklin-gothic-ext-comp-urw; font-weight: 700; font-style: normal; font-size: 15px; opacity: 1; color: rgb(63, 63, 63); transform: translate(7px, 0px) scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);">SIGN&nbsp;UP</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;"></div>
    <div style="display: none;">
      <div style="transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(0.5, 0.5) rotate(0deg);">
        <div role="img">
          <img src="images/lsloginform/newskin/try_it_MO.png?1444665385167">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="transform: translate(0px, 75px) scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);">
        <canvas height="7" width="75" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 75px; height: 7px;"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div style="transform: translate(0px, 82px) scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);">
        <div style="font-family: franklin-gothic-ext-comp-urw; font-weight: 700; font-style: normal; font-size: 15px; opacity: 1; color: rgb(63, 63, 63); transform: translate(7px, 0px) scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);">SIGN&nbsp;UP</div>
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;"></div>
    <div style="display: none;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Specific example, I'd like to the xpath of the above div utilizing the "SIGN UP" text at the end of the HTML. How do I go about doing that?

The application I test on is finicky as all hell, and being able to select by that attribute would make my life much easier. The reason this is a problem is because I need 3 different methods of grabbing an xpath: One for the button as normal, one for the hover, and another because the button changes momentarily when it is clicked. Most of my automation scripts look something like:

```
    public class changeLanguageLogin {
        public void run(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement changeLanguage = getWebElement(driver, "xpath", "img", "src", "select_application_language_normal");
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.moveToElement(changeLanguage).build().perform();
            WebElement changeLanguageMO = getWebElement(driver, "xpath", "img", "src", "select_application_language_hover");
            changeLanguageMO.click();
            WebElement changeLanguageClicked = getWebElement(driver, "xpath", "img", "src", "select_application_language_pushed");
            changeLanguageClicked.click();
        }


      private static By buildXPathExpression(String htmlElement, String attributeName, String attributeValue)
      {
          return By.xpath("//"+htmlElement+"[contains(@"+attributeName+",'"+attributeValue+"')]");
      }

      private static By buildCSSExpression(String htmlElement, String attributeName, String attributeValue)
      {
          return By.cssSelector(""+htmlElement+"["+attributeName+"='"+attributeValue+"']");
      }

      private static WebElement getWebElement(WebDriver driver, String operation, String htmlElement, String attributeName, String attributeValue)
      {
          By byObj = null;
          WebElement webElementObj = null;
          if(operation!= null)
          {
              if(operation.equals("xpath"))
              {
                  byObj = buildXPathExpression(htmlElement,attributeName,attributeValue);
              }
              else if(operation.equals("cssSelector"))
              {
                  byObj = buildCSSExpression(htmlElement,attributeName,attributeValue);
              }
          }
          if(byObj != null)
          {
              webElementObj = driver.findElement(byObj);
          }

          return webElementObj;
      }
}
```

Many, many, many times a day, one method of defining the xpath simply "will not work" and I have to scrounge around for another one. The goal is to not use any "hard coded" xpaths, as that was problematic when I had began the job.

So the answer I'm looking for: Define an xpath by the text in the HTML, "SIGN UP".

Comment: if you can reach this element by css, xpath, .. you can get the text by `.getText()` or  `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` .

Comment: The problem is I can't get to it by css or xpath.

Comment: then you should give more html :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This response will not help if you are bound to only **xpath** or
>   **css** lookups.

**Option 1**

If you would be willing to add another case to your helper method I'm thinking that *By.linkText* may do what you're wanting?

```
  /**
   * @param linkText The exact text to match against
   * @return a By which locates A elements by the exact text it displays
   */
  public static By linkText(final String linkText) {
    if (linkText == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Cannot find elements when link text is null.");

    return new ByLinkText(linkText);
  }
```

Or possibly *By.partialLinkText*

```
  /**
   * @param linkText The text to match against
   * @return a By which locates A elements that contain the given link text
   */
  public static By partialLinkText(final String linkText) {
    if (linkText == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Cannot find elements when link text is null.");

    return new ByPartialLinkText(linkText);
  }
```

This would potentially be an issue if you're testing against a system that has been internationalized.  Depending on the environment the locale of the user/browser would change the text you're looking for.

This can also be a maintenance issue if the text changes.

**Option 2**

If you have control of the HTML, you may consider adding id's to the elements on the page.  With that then you can use the *By.id* lookup.  From some of my preliminary research the element id is seen as one of the more reliable and consistent paths.

```
/**
   * @param id The value of the "id" attribute to search for
   * @return a By which locates elements by the value of the "id" attribute.
   */
  public static By id(final String id) {
    if (id == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Cannot find elements with a null id attribute.");

    return new ById(id);
  }
```

**Option 3**

My final suggestion would be to try to implement your own *By* lookup.  I would fall short on suggesting an implementation for the lookup, but if this behavior is what you're needing then you should be aware that you could potentially create a subclass to do what you're wanting.

Best of Luck.

Answer (score 1):

For old time inlie style css, you generate the css selector depends on the style written for the div like `"div[style*='paste_style_attribute']"`. However this method is not dependable because of duplication of same style.

For the following div:

```
<div style="font-family: franklin-gothic-ext-comp-urw; font-weight: 700; font-style: normal; font-size: 15px; opacity: 1; color: rgb(63, 63, 63); transform: translate(7px, 0px) scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);">SIGN&nbsp;UP</div>
```

You can generate the following css selector:

```
"div[style*='font-family: franklin-gothic-ext-comp-urw; font-weight: 700; font-style: normal; font-size: 15px; opacity: 1; color: rgb(63, 63, 63); transform: translate(7px, 0px) scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);']"
```

Java code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[style*='font-family: franklin-gothic-ext-comp-urw; font-weight: 700; font-style: normal; font-size: 15px; opacity: 1; color: rgb(63, 63, 63); transform: translate(7px, 0px) scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);']"))
```